# VIM 8.2 Backspace Delete behavior

Tags: vim

I uninstalled vim 8.1 which is the available version through my package manager and installed 8.2 from source. But Backspace and Delete buttons behave in a different way in this version.

If you are in insert mode and press Backspace then it does not delete or move indentation to the left. Delete button in insert mode deletes up to the end of the current line and does not continue to the next one.

Why these changes in behavior and how do I revert to the previous one?

Comment: PS please dont cross-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the docs. You need to set:

`set backspace=indent,eol,start`

My previous installation was vim-gtk. I suppose this package has this value set as default.

Now both backspace and delete work as before.

Comment: Most OS vendors ship with a set of defaults that are more user friendly than the VIm defaults.  You could try installing an updated package from a newer version of your distro or a compatible one (e.g., Debian unstable) if you want to keep those defaults.